# Scraping table in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

Could someone please help me scrape data from the big table on https://www.statsinsider.com.au/prediction-results?fbclid=IwAR18wxeCq_ygxLG1v2JEe3YqBNNS6krzNnOQULYp4IZihQY6JMgHwzpIl6o

I have some foundation here:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
url = 'https://www.statsinsider.com.au/prediction-results?fbclid=IwAR18wxeCq_ygxLG1v2JEe3YqBNNS6krzNnOQULYp4IZihQY6JMgHwzpIl6o'
r = session.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.html.html,'html.parser')
stat_table = soup.find('table')
```

this outputs the following, which doesn't seem to be the entire table. Help appreciated, thanks!

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th class="to-hide">Sport</th>
<th>Team</th>
<th class="to-hide">Bet Type</th>
<th>Odds</th>
<th class="to-hide">Bet</th>
<th>Result</th>
<th>Profit/Loss</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="match in recentResults">
<td>{{match.Date}}</td>
<td class="to-hide">{{match.Sport}}</td>
<td>{{match.Team}}</td>
<td class="to-hide">{{match.Type}}</td>
<td>${{match.Odds}}</td>
<td class="to-hide">${{match.Bet}}</td>
<td>{{match.Result}}</td>
<td class="green" ng-if="match.Return &gt; 0">${{match.Return}}</td>
<td class="red" ng-if="match.Return &lt; 0">${{match.Return}}</td>
<td ng-if="match.Return == 0"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate *It doesn't seem like the normal simple table I'm used to scraping*? What *exactly* are you unable to do here?

Comment: @KeyurPotdar The table doesn't appear to have a class and there are weird attributes like `ng-repeat="match in recentResults"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already using requests, you may want to consider using [Requests-HTML](https://www.statsinsider.com.au/prediction-results?fbclid=IwAR18wxeCq_ygxLG1v2JEe3YqBNNS6krzNnOQULYp4IZihQY6JMgHwzpIl6o). Although it's capabilities are not as advanced as [selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/), it is quite useful in cases like this where you just want the page rendered.

To Install

```
pip install requests-html
```

The table in the link you provided can be easily **scraped** using Requests-HTML

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
url = 'https://www.statsinsider.com.au/prediction-results?fbclid=IwAR18wxeCq_ygxLG1v2JEe3YqBNNS6krzNnOQULYp4IZihQY6JMgHwzpIl6o'
r = session.get(url)
r.html.render()
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.html.html,'html.parser')
stat_table = soup.find('table')
print(stat_table)
```

Output

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th class="to-hide">Sport</th>
<th>Team</th>
<th class="to-hide">Bet Type</th>
<th>Odds</th>
<th class="to-hide">Bet</th>
<th>Result</th>
<th>Profit/Loss</th>
</tr>

...

<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="match in recentResults">
<td class="ng-binding">17/09</td>
<td class="to-hide ng-binding">NFL</td>
<td class="ng-binding">NO</td>
<td class="to-hide ng-binding">Line</td>
<td class="ng-binding">$1.91</td>
<td class="to-hide ng-binding">$25</td>
<td class="ng-binding">LOSE</td>
<!-- ngIf: match.Return > 0 -->
<!-- ngIf: match.Return < 0 --><td class="red ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="match.Return &lt; 0">$-25.00</td><!-- end ngIf: match.Return < 0 -->
<!-- ngIf: match.Return == 0 -->
</tr><!-- end ngRepeat: match in recentResults -->
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! Please see my updated question in which I've done as you suggested.

Comment: @Programmer I was able to get the entire table as output. However also try this `r.html.render(sleep=5)` in the code instead of `r.html.render()`

Comment: I actually had to remove that part of the code since I get error `Cannot use HTMLSession within an existing event loop. Use AsyncHTMLSession instead.` I'm running in jupyter maybe that's why?

Comment: @Programmer The code won't work without that part. It is that line that renders the page. I am trying from my console not from jupyter. Can you please try outside jupyter?

Comment: @Bitto Bennichan I faced the same problem`Cannot use HTMLSession within an existing event loop. Use AsyncHTMLSession instead.` How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

This table is created **dynamically** using AJAX call.

The page is fetching 3 JSON documents - one of them is the one that you are looking for.

1. https://gazza.statsinsider.com.au/results.json?sport=NFL
2. https://gazza.statsinsider.com.au/sportladder.json?sport=nba
3. https://gazza.statsinsider.com.au/upcoming.json

All you need to do is HTTP GET to each of the URL's above and check which one of them is the table mode. Once you find the right URL, use requests and get the data.